# Error: mismatch "${body.toString()}" em Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Eu tenho este erro 'Type mismatch' neste código ´${body.toString()}´:

```
    fun fetchJson(){

    val url = "http://localhost:8080/matematica3/naoAutomatica/get"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            println("${e?.message}")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            editTextRespostaAviario?.text = "${body.toString()}"
        }

    })
}
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Por que não reutilizar a variável declarada acima que já tem a resposta? `editTextRespostaAviario?.text = body`

Comment: Não dá dessa forma @LeonardoLima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa sintaxe de acesso à propriedades (usando `.`), você deve passar um `Editable` para o `EditText`. Para passar uma `String`, use o setter:

```
editTextRespostaAviario?.setText("${body.toString()}"
```

Note que a sintaxe acima seria redundante, já que você está usando um `String Template` para passar somente uma String. O ideal é passar a String diretamente:

```
editTextRespostaAviario?.setText(body.toString());
```

Também é redundante chamar `toString` no body, já que ele em si já é uma `String`. O seguinte deve ser suficiente para você:

```
editTextRespostaAviario?.setText(body);
```

Comment: obrigada, dessa forma já não tem erros